# Android: most optimal way to save progress

Tags: android, position, save

My app lets users browse through slideshows of images. Every slideshow is a collection of all the images in a certain folder. Usually a folder has about 50-60 images. I want to save the image position in the slideshow the user is at when he/she exits that folder's slideshow. What would be the most optimal way for this?

Comment: I think this post should provide a good minimal working example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can save this persistently (across application launches by using a shared preferences).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your class (which has your save data) into a json string and can use SharedPreferances to serialize the string into a file. When you want to laod your progress, you can read the SharedPreference value and load your class using Gson.